# Changing default Google Maps Api's default zoomControls Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can you change the default image of the Google Maps Api zoom Controls in order to create my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot change the image of the zoom control to anything other than the three options provided by Google:

> The Zoom control may appear in one of the following style options:
>
> **google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL** displays a mini-zoom control, consisting of only + and - buttons. This style is appropriate for
>   small maps. On touch devices, this control displays as + and - buttons
>   that are responsive to touch events.
>
> **google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE** displays the standard zoom slider control. On touch devices, this control displays as + and -
>   buttons that are responsive to touch events.
>
> **google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT** picks an appropriate zoom control based on the map's size and the device on which the map is
>   running.

You can however build [custom controls](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomDrawing) and place them on the map.  You will have to set the appropriate event handlers and manage the state of the control, but it could be done.

A slider control might be a bit tricky, but if you just wanted zoom in and zoom out buttons you could get away with not managing state.

the events would look similar to this:

```
//zoom in control click event
google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomIn, 'click', function() {
   var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if(currentZoomLevel != 21){
     map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);
    }
 });

//zoom out control click event
google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomOut, 'click', function() {
   var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if(currentZoomLevel != 0){
     map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);
   }
 });
```